# Increasing counter of duplicated rows (Not by PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

say `select IDX, SUB_IDX, NAME from MYTABLE order by IDX, SUB_IDX` results :

```
IDX SUB_IDX NAME
1   20  aaa
2   22  bbb
3   22  ccc
4   23  ddd
5   23  eee
6   23  fff
```

`IDX` is PK and I want to count of duplicated of consecutive `SUB_IDX` like this :

```
IDX SUB_IDX count   NAME
1   20      1       aaa
2   22      1       bbb
3   22      2       ccc
4   23      1       ddd
5   23      2       eee
6   23      3       fff
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? Please read [ask]

Comment: @EngineerDollery I'm trying this by PL/SQL. But I need to do this by single SQL if possible. Because.. creating new PL/SQL is not welcomed by Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to count of duplicated of ***consecutive*** `SUB_IDX`

Because of your ***consecutive*** requirement, the query gets more complicated. Your sample data is a bit too simplistic and doesn't clearly show what your expected output would be when non-consecutive duplicate `SUB_IDX` values occur.

Still, assuming I am understanding correctly, combining some analytic functions, it is possible. Perhaps someone can find a way to simplify the query:

```
with grp_starts as (
  select idx, sub_idx, name,
         case when sub_idx = lag(sub_idx) over (order by idx)
           then 0 else 1 end as is_grp_start
  from mytable),
grps as (
  select idx, sub_idx, name,
         sum(is_grp_start) over (order by idx) as grp_id
    from grp_starts)
select idx, 
       sub_idx,
       row_number() over (partition by grp_id order by idx) as count,
       name
  from grps
```

Comment: It seems the OP really meant consecutive by idx. Start of group is fine, but for this type of problem the so called tabibitosan (or "equal differences") method is more efficient. https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680

Comment: @mathguy: I could be mistaken, but I don't think that method works in this case. If you know how to do it though, I would love to see it.

Comment: I was thinking of offering it, just for completeness. I will do so in a few minutes.

Comment: @mathguy: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `count` windowing function:

```
select
  idx, sub_idx,
  count (1) over (partition by sub_idx order by idx) as count,
  name
from MYTABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but @sstan's answer is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you didn't really mean "consecutive" ("consecutive" by what ordering criteria?) and instead you just want to assign consecutive numbers to rows with the same SUB_INDEX ... and assuming you want to assign those numbers in increasing (alphabetical) order of the NAME:

```
select idx, sub_idx, row_number() over (partition by sub_idx order by name) as ct, name
from table_name
```

count is a reserved word in Oracle; don't use it as a column name. (Same with DATE, LAST, etc.)

Comment: I don't think `partition by idx` is what is desired in this case

Comment: @DaveCosta - You are right, thank you; I meant by `sub_idx`. I said one thing (in the first paragraph) and then coded another. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is another solution, very similar to sstan's but using the "tabibitosan" or "equal differences" method for creating the groups (instead of the "start of group" method, which is more general but, in this case, less efficient since it reads the same rows twice instead of once).

The general class of problems where the tabibitosan method can be applied is known as "gaps and islands" problems, or finding sequences of consecutive rows (according to some well-specified ordering) with the same value in one or more column(s).

Notice the difference of two calls to `row_number()` in the `grps` subquery - this replaces the "groups" created with the "start of group" flag followed by a running sum. Also, notice that once the "groups" by difference of row numbers is formed, the groups used in the last (outer) query are by this difference AND `sub_idx`, NOT by the `row_number()` differences alone (that is a common misunderstanding of the method).

I put a link to an OTN "community document" regarding the tabibitosan method in a comment to sstan's solution.

In some cases, one could use `idx` itself instead of `row_number() over (order by idx)` - when `idx` are serial numbers (consecutive). That is poor programming though, since it relies on specific "physical" knowledge of the data. The solution I wrote below does not rely on such knowledge (and to demonstrate, I added more rows, where the `idx` is not consecutive numbers).

```
with 
     t ( idx, sub_idx, name ) as (
       select  1, 20, 'aaa' from dual union all
       select  2, 22, 'bbb' from dual union all
       select  3, 22, 'ccc' from dual union all
       select  4, 23, 'ddd' from dual union all
       select  5, 23, 'eee' from dual union all
       select  6, 23, 'fff' from dual union all
       select  7, 22, 'ggg' from dual union all
       select  9, 22, 'hhh' from dual union all
       select 12, 20, 'iii' from dual union all
       select 18, 20, 'jjj' from dual
     ),
     grps ( idx, sub_idx, name, grp ) as (
       select idx, sub_idx, name,
              row_number() over (order by idx) - 
                  row_number() over (partition by sub_idx order by idx)
       from   t
     )
select idx, sub_idx, 
       row_number() over (partition by sub_idx, grp order by idx) as ct,
       name
from grps
order by idx   --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

**Output**:

```
       IDX    SUB_IDX         CT  NAME
---------- ---------- ----------  ----
         1         20          1  aaa
         2         22          1  bbb
         3         22          2  ccc
         4         23          1  ddd
         5         23          2  eee
         6         23          3  fff
         7         22          1  ggg
         9         22          2  hhh
        12         20          1  iii
        18         20          2  jjj

 10 rows selected
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @sstan  - I didn't invent it, I just learned it... the beauty of SO and OTN!